# "blocked by CORS policy" when trying to redirect with expressJS

Tags: javascript, express

I have a problem when trying to redirect with ExpressJS, I made a login system that get a post request and if the user is exist the page suppose to redirect, but instead Cors is blocking it.

This is the request:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

    try{    
       let usersData = await  getFiles(__dirname + '/users.json');
       let parsedUsers = JSON.parse(usersData);
       let userChecker;
       for(let i = 0; i < parsedUsers.length; i++){
       if(parsedUsers[i].userName === req.body.userName){
           userChecker = 1;
           break;
       } 
       }

       if(!userChecker){
        console.log(`${req.body.userName} Not exist`);}

        else {
        console.log(`${req.body.userName} Approved`);
        res.redirect('/')
       }
        }
     catch (err) {
      if(err) throw err
    };
})
```

This is the error it sends at the console:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/users/login' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4000/users/login') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Can anyone tell whats the problem with that cors?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Same problem here.

Answer (score 3):

For this, you need to send some header from the server so the browser will know the domain is allowed to access.
You can try this 
**Manual header**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

// your code
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

});
```

**Cors npm module:**

```
//run this command for install the cors module
npm install cors // install the cors

// use it in your code
app.use(cors()) // will enable cors

// your code
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

});
```

Comment: Already installed cors and add ``` app.use(cors())``` at the index page. Should I put it at the router page?

Comment: The '/login' post is from another file called users.js, I'm using express router. in my main file "index.js" I added "app.use(cors())". What I'm asking is should I add router.use(cors()) to the users.js file?

Answer (score 0):

This is because CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is not allowed yet in your project. You can install [cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) package for this.

```
npm install cors
```

Then do this,

```
app.use(cors()) // It will enable all cors requests
```

That's it. You are good to go now. It is the simplest way to handle cors.

Comment: Actually my app is using cors in the main page. Maybe I have to add it in the users router file?

Comment: @SahiBalata I think your main page i.e. index file should be enough.

Comment: It's not enough, still blocking the request.

Comment: I think I got the problem... I should add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'... But I don't how to add the syntax and where...

Comment: @SahiBalata I think that is what cors should do. Check for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/1055241

Comment: @SahiBalata Hi! experiencing the same issue, have you worked this out somehow?